# How to fix laravel 5 session expiring after refresh or going on another page?

Tags: session, authentication, laravel-5, logout, laravel-5.1

I'm using laravel Auth. When I  login into my website all works great. When I try to refresh or go to another page (still using Auth middleware) my session is expired, I'm directly logged-out and I must login again. How can I fix this so I remain logged in when refreshing the page or browsing to another?

Comment: What command are you using to authenticate a user? What session driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using the default driver 'Eloquent'.

Comment: Your using eloquent for your [session driver](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#session-drivers)?

Comment: @SiriusBlack have you solved this? I'm stuck with this problem as well and have not found a way to solve it yet